# Why is my pagenumbering not working the way I want it to?

Tags: numbering

So I want to have Frontmatter with Roman signs and then after the table of content, I want it to be Arabic. But my Nomenclature starts with an Arabic "1" and my introduction with "2" I tried `\pagenumbering{gobble}` but it's not working. Can anybody help me?

[image].

```
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\input{Frontmatter/Frontpage.tex}
\pagecolor{white}
\newgeometry{top=2.81cm, bottom=2.75cm, outer=2.5cm, inner=2.5cm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\cleardoublepage 
\input{Frontmatter/Copyright.tex}
\cleardoublepage 
\pagestyle{main}
\input{Frontmatter/Approval.tex}
\cleardoublepage 
\input{Frontmatter/Abstract.tex}
\cleardoublepage 
\input{Frontmatter/Resume}
\cleardoublepage  
\tableofcontents
%\pagenumbering{gobble}
\input{Frontmatter/Nomenclature}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\setcounter{page}{1}
\input{Chapters/01_Introduction.tex}
%\cleardoublepage 
\input{Chapters/02_Cables}
%\cleardoublepage 
\input{Chapters/03_FEM}
%\cleardoublepage 
\input{Chapters/04_Damping}
%\cleardoublepage 
\input{Chapters/05_Experiments}
%\cleardoublepage 
\input{Chapters/06_Discussion}
%\cleardoublepage 
\input{Chapters/07_Conclusion}
%\cleardoublepage 
\input{Chapters/08_Furtherworks}
%\cleardoublepage
```

Comment: Please extend this into a full but minimal example, you haven';t mentioned which class or packages you are using and you're inputting stuff we do not have access to so we cannot test your code.  If you are using a class that supports it, it is better to use `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`, the former uses roman page numbering and disables section numbers etc. `\mainmatter` brings things back to normal and starts from 1.

Comment: you are so carefully putting a \cleardoublepage everywhere, only before \pagenumbering{arabic} you missed it ...

Comment: Ulrikke Ficher it worked!! Thank you so much!